# Save rotate image onto server

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to save rotate image onto the server
I found some solution but its not working..
**UPDATE**

Image path is in xml..
here is the code:

```
public Boolean saveRotateImg(string path) 
{
    string new_path="/Job_Files/"+Job_ID+"/"+GroupName+"/Images/"+path;
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(new_path)) 
    {
        //rotate the picture by 90 degrees and re-save the picture as a Jpeg
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        image.Save(output, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to do that or any other way for that..

Comment: Could you add some more details? for example, the new_path is this where the image must be stored to? And is this also the location where the image is coming from? And of course what do you exactly mean with 'not working'?

Comment: You are trying to load the image from the `new_path` location it seems to me that this is the location where you want to store it. shouldn't the image be loaded from `path` and stored to `new_path`?

Comment: Thats correct..will u please tell me how to do that..I am not getting any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above it should be something like this:

```
public Boolean saveRotateImg(string path) 
{
    string new_path="/Job_Files/"+Job_ID+"/"+GroupName+"/Images/"+path;
    // Load the image from the original path
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path)) 
    {
        //rotate the picture by 90 degrees and re-save the picture as a Jpeg
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

        // Save the image to the new_path
        image.Save(new_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
}
```

Though you will have to make sure that the variables `path` and `new_path` contain the full path + filename of the image.

**EDIT:** I've removed the image.Dispose() as the `using` will take care of this. Also I've replaced the `System.IO.File.Delete(path)` call to the end of the routine, not sure if this is required, but in this case it will never interfere with the usage of the image.

Comment: it throws an err of filenotfound..my image file path is like `<Image group="AiringCupboard0">
  <File_name>AiringCupboard0_1.jpg</File_name>
 <Path>/Job_Files/74/10_AiringCupboard0/Images/AiringCupboard0_1.jpg</Path>
</Image>`

Comment: In that case you must need to make sure, like I said, that the path is a correct path to a file.

Comment: in `path` m only getting `AiringCupboard0_1.jpg`..`Image.FromFile(path)` will able to find whole path??

Comment: No, in path you will need to have the full path (file and folder) like: 
`/Job_Files/74/10_AiringCupboard0/Images/AiringCupboard0_1.jpg`

If you have that you might also want to take another look to the line where you construct the `new_path` as you append the whole `path` to the end of it (you might only need the filename).

Comment: Yeah u right...It was only path err now getting err of `A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

Comment: Could it be that the `new_path` leads to a folder that does not exist? You can use:

`if (!Directory.Exists(new_path))  { Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetFullPath(new_path)); }`

Comment: Last question if I have `/Job_Files/74/10_AiringCupboard0/Images/AiringCupboard0_1.jpg` where `10_` is always changed then how can I write in my path if my path is like `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Job_Files/" + Job_ID + "/10_" + GroupName + "/Images/" + path);`